# How power system handle unbalanced load?

Tags: power, transformer, generator, power-engineering, unbalanced

how a delta connected primary winding of three phase distribution transformer  tackle unbalanced load of three phase 4 wire unbalanced load(unbalanced load is quite common due to supply of single phase equipment using neutral wire)?

Comment: It tackles it a lot better than a star primary.

Comment: Zarzis - are we done here now? Is there something you still don't understand with my answer?

Comment: Thank you dear Andy. You have helped me in a lot of thinking. Just one thing I am not clear, when there is unbalance current in the secondary star then that unbalance current should be reflected to primary phase winding(lets assume it is delta connected) and cause unbalanced current in the power system. Is it normal that power system run with unbalance current?

Comment: Yes, quite significant imbalance currents can occur but, with multiple users of electricity, statistically the imbalance gets less problematic but, there can be occasions when it appears bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *....three phase 4 wire unbalanced load*

That implies a star wound secondary so, with star connected secondary, each load is exclusively connected across one of the limbs in the star output. This, of course, means between a phase voltage and the neutral-point (the forth wire). This also means that whatever load current is taken on one phase has no impact on the load currents of the other two windings.

> *delta connected primary winding of three phase distribution
> transformer*

With a delta primary, each winding directly connects across an incoming line voltage AND, importantly, the relevance of all of this is that each phase of the transformer can be regarded as equivalent to a single phase transformer.

So, if you are happy that a single phase transformer can "tackle" a range of loads and, will do so irrespective of the other two phases that might be working along side it then you have your answer.

A better question would be *why a star connected transformer primary might be appalling at dealing with unbalanced loads* but, you didn't ask that and nobody likes folk changing their mind on questions so fundamentally.